# Copyright symbol in batch

Tags: batch-file, symbols

I'm trying output a copyright symbol in DOS using echo. For example:

```
echo Copyright(c) by Nastrodamus
```

How do I get that (c) symbol in batch? The regular © doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the console's font does not support a copywrite character.  The Alt-0169 character in Windows Times Roman font that shows a copywrite character is in fact a 'corner' like character in the Terminal font.

Commonly a (C) is used in its place in 'console' applications.

For a frequently typed symbol such as "©", the keyboard shortcut is probably faster than starting another program.

There should be a way in later Win's to do that...

Comment: As of 2021 it's still not supported. 

Answer (score 3):

In your editor press `ALT`, keep it pressed while you enter `184` then release `ALT`

edit: done with 0169: [image: .]

done with 184: [image: ..]

(active codepage: 850)

Comment: try `0169` instead of `184` (the triple-numbers depend on the local codepage. Not sure, but I think, the quad-numbers don't.

Comment: This gives ╕ for me, same as nephi12

Comment: the 0169 gives me © here but in cmd it gives me a normal c

Comment: same. this is because cmd does not support that character. see here: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2550